# How to make links clickable in htmltooltip of amcharts v5 maps

Tags: amcharts5

amcharts v5 supports HTML in tooltip using tooltipHTML but when any link is added to the tooltipHTML, the link is not clickable.
Issue can be here https://codepen.io/yourgautam/pen/wvQdajv

```
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
  tooltipHTML: "{name} <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>SEE THE PROJECTS</a>",
  interactive: true,
  calculateVisualCenter:true,
  tooltipPosition:"fixed",
  interactionsEnabled:true,
  keepTargetHover: true
});
```